# topological sequential space $(X,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose in topological space $(X,\tau)$ every countably compact is closed.Let  $(X,\tau)$ be sequential space.

(1): If every  infinite subset $A \subseteq X$ is closed, will $A$  be **discreet** in $X$?

(2)If there is $x \in \overline{C} - C$ and $\{ x_n :n \in \omega\}$ in **infinite** and **non-closed** $ C \subseteq A$ s.t $\{ x_n :n \in \omega\}$ converge to $x$,  won`t $x_n$ be an **accumulation point** for $\{ x_n :n \in \omega\}$?why?

Comment: maybe you should change the title of the question to make it a bit more informative

Comment: Furthermore I don't know exact what the question is

Comment: If every infinite $A\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$, then $X$ itself has the discrete topology. What did you really mean to ask? If you’re trying to understand the proof some theorem in a paper, please identify the paper and the theorem, so that we can see what’s really going on here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That doesn't follow directly, if $X$ is finite, then the topology doesn't need to be discrete

Comment: @BrainM.Scott: I want to say if $X$ is sequential and  every countably compact is closed has  this property that  every infinite $A \subseteq X$ has infinite subset $B \subseteq A$ s.t  has finite accumulation point in $X$.

Comment: @BrainM.Scott: it is theorem 3.4 from " On minimal strongly KC-spaces by Weihua Sun; Yuming Xu; Ning Li"

Comment: @Dominic: True, but not really relevant to the context in which the OP is working. (That might not be evident from this question alone, but this is one of many related questions.)

Comment: @Ebi: Okay; I’ll take a look, but I may not get to it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. This is true in general, not just for sequential strongly $KC$ spaces: if $A$ is an infinite subset of a space $X$, and every infinite subset of $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is a closed, discrete subset of $X$. $A$ is an infinite subset of itself, so $A$ is closed in $X$. For each $x\in A$ the set $A\setminus\{x\}$ is an infinite subset of $A$, so it’s closed in $X$, and $\{x\}=A\setminus(A\setminus\{x\})$ is therefore open in $A$. Thus, for each $x\in A$ there is an open $U_x$ in $X$ such that $U_x\cap A=\{x\}$, and $A$ is discrete as well as closed in $X$.
2. Now suppose that $X$ is a sequential $KC$ space, and that $C$ is an infinite subset of $X$ that isn’t closed in $X$. Since $X$ is sequential, $C$ is not sequentially closed, and there are therefore an $x\in(\operatorname{cl}C)\setminus C$ and a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $C$ converging to $x$. Let $S=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$, and let $K=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}\cup\{x\}$; then $K$ is compact, and since $X$ is $KC$, $K$ is closed in $X$. Let $y\in X$. If $y\notin K$, then $X\setminus K$ is an open nbhd of $y$ disjoint from $S$, so $y$ is not an accumulation point of $S$. Suppose now that $y=x_m$ for some $m\in\omega$; the subsequence $\langle x_n:n>m\rangle$ still converges to $x$, so $\{x\}\cup\{x_n:n>m\}$ is compact and therefore closed in $X$. Let $U=X\setminus\big(\{x\}\cup\{x_n:n>m\}\big)$; $U$ is open in $X$. $X$ is $T_1$, so $\{x_n:n<m\}$ is closed in $X$, and therefore $U\setminus\{x_n:n<m\}$ is an open nbhd of $x_m$. Finally, $U\cap S=\{x_m\}$, so $x_m$ is not an accumulation point of $S$. Thus, $x$ is the unique accumulation point of $S$.

These two points together show that every sequential $KC$ space has the $FDS$ property; the space need not be strongly $KC$. Let $A$ be any infinite subset of such a space. If $A$ has an infinite subset $C$ that is not closed in $X$, part (2) shows that $C$ (and therefore $A$) has an infinite subset $S$ with only one accumulation point. If every infinite subset of $C$ is closed in $X$, part (1) shows that $C$ is closed and discrete and therefore has no accumulation points.